# How to reference a field within the current form only? -- JQuery beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried all variations of the following:

```
$(this).("input[name='email']").val();
```

Comment: you will have to put more code (your form, your JS code etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `this` is the `form` element, and you want to find `input` elements only with that form, you have a couple of options. You could use `this` as a context:

```
$("input[name='email']", this).val();
```

Or you could `find` the elements within `this`:

```
$(this).find("input[name='email']").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context of this code, James has provided an answer for targeting inputs if you already have the desired form as your "context". But since there aren't a lot of ways to end up in that situation, and since you're looking for values I'm guessing that you're firing this code from a button inside the form, maybe a submit button?

In that case you'll have to traverse up the DOM before you can target your inputs and stay within the same form. Something like:

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input[name="email"]').val();
```